# How to assign an input parameter for a function including awk?

Tags: bashrc, awk, alias

I am making some shortcuts for my account in a computation cluster. When I submit a job, the system assigns a job-ID (JOBID) to my calculation. To list all my calculations, I made an alias

```
alias j="queue -u myuser-ID"
```

which gives an output similar to

```
         JOBID     NAME     USER     ST       TIME 
      13716868   job_samp   myuserid  R    2:02:55
```

Then the system creates a temporary directory with the name job.JOBID in which the output files are stored. To reach this directory, I wrote a function:

```
jj() { cd ~/many/many/files/job."$1"; }
```

which takes me to this temporary file with the command 'job JOBID'. To save some more keystrokes I want to write another function which takes the listed JOBID by my alias 'j' and take me to the temporary file. When I have just one job, the following function works

```
tt() { r=$(j | awk 'FNR>=2&&NR {print $1}'); jj $r; }
```

and command 'tt' takes me to that file. However, if I have more than one calculation (which is most of the case), the last function is useless since it will always take me to the first job listed. What I am trying to do is assign a variable to FNR bit of the 'tt' function so that when I type, let's say, 'tt 3' it will take me to the third job's directory. I tried using -v option as in

```
tt() { r=$(j | awk -v 'FNR=$2&&NR {print $1}'); jj $r; }
```

but I get an error saying 'FNR' is not a proper variable. How can I make this work ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Awkk's `-v` argument takes a `name=value` pair, allowing you to use `name` as a variable inside your awk program. So

```
tt() { r=$(j | awk -v id="$2" 'FNR=id && NR {print $1}'); jj $r; }
```

(TBH I'm not sure why the `&& NR` is necessary here, or why you're distinguishing between `NR` and `FNR` when you are only passing a single input (stdin) to awk.)

Comment: Thank you ! As you pointed, the '&& NR {print $1}' bit is needless and confusing. I thought I needed it as if I am determining an element of a matrix, but when I get rid of that part and just use 
    tt() { r=$(j | awk -v id="$1" 'FNR=id'); jj $r; }
it worked perfectly fine.